# Semi-parallax effect for multiple bottom backgrounds -- very complicated (for me)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, background-image

This is too complicated for my little brain.

I am trying to make a parallax effect that only involves backgrounds, leaving alone the main content markup (a regular wordpress loop).

The backgrounds are all in the div `#page` which takes the whole document.

```
#page {
    background:url("../../../myfiles/headers/mandala-bottom.png") no-repeat scroll bottom center, url("../../../myfiles/backgrounds/top-fade.png") repeat-x scroll top center, url("../../../myfiles/backgrounds/bottom-fade.png")repeat-x scroll bottom center; }

body {
    background:url("../../../myfiles/backgrounds/small-fill.jpg") repeat scroll top; }
```

The top background scrolls up at its own pace, the fill scrolls normally in the middle of the page. It's in the body and it stays below. So far so good.

I then want to to make the two bottom backgrounds, bottom-fade and mandala-bottom to come up at their own pace (mandala-bottom is on top of bottom-fade).

They do: but for the life of me **I cannot make them stop exactly at the bottom**, I think mainly because `scrollTop()` and `offset()` are all based on top...

You would think it is only a matter of subtracting values, but I find that viewport height makes all the difference. If the viewport changes, the images end at a higher or lower position, although with very small differences.

**I guess I need to factor the viewport in the calculation? but I don't know how.**

Here's my whole code, I put a lot of comments in it, hopefully it will be not too difficult to understand.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    "use strict"; 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $win = $(window);

    $('div#page').each(function(){

        //set an arbitrary speed
        var scroll_speed1 = 8;

        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

        //set heights of backgrounds (any easy way to get this dynamically?)
        var topFade = 600;
        var bottomFade = 870;
        var mandalaBottom = 457;

        var $this = $(this);

        //set background-attachment here, so that in style.css top-fade can be "scroll"
        //needed in case the script breaks
        $this.css("background-attachment", "scroll, fixed, scroll");

        //set all the initial positions
        //the idea is that if the images are down below (= higher number)
        //they will scroll up faster, at a matching speed (= number dimishing faster)
        var bgP1 = ( ($this.outerHeight()*2) + mandalaBottom ); //mandala-bottom
        var bgP2 = $this.offset().top; //top-fade
        var bgP3 = ($this.outerHeight()+(bottomFade)); //bottom-fade
        var initialValue = "center " + bgP1 + "px," + "center " + bgP2 + "px," + "center " + bgP3 + "px";

        //put the images in the css
        $this.css("background-position", initialValue);

        //bind to the scroll event  
        $(window).scroll(function() {

            //percent between viewport and height of page
            var viewportDiff = percentChange($this.outerHeight(), viewportHeight);
            console.log("the percent between viewport and height of page is: " + viewportDiff+ "%");

            //percent between position of pic and height of page
            var perDiff = percentChange(bgP1, $this.outerHeight());
            console.log("the percent between position of pic and height of page is: " + perDiff);

       /*   1) $win.scrollTop() = position of the scroll (increasing number) 
            2) perDiff = the proportion between the page and the position of the pic (%)
            3) viewportDiff= the proportion between the page and the viewport (%)
            4) $this.outerHeight() = height of the page
            => scroll + the x% of scroll (given by the difference with 
            the position of the pic) - the x% of page (given by the difference 
            between viewport and page) + the height of the image   */             
            var numberToSubstract = ( $win.scrollTop() + percentOf($win.scrollTop(), perDiff) - percentOf(viewportDiff, $this.outerHeight() ) + (mandalaBottom/2) );
            console.log("the initial position of the pic was: " + bgP1);
            console.log("we have substracted this much: " + numberToSubstract);
            var bgNP1 = bgP1 - numberToSubstract - (mandalaBottom);
            console.log("the pic now is here: " + bgNP1);
            console.log("the height of the page is: " + $this.outerHeight());            


            //this calculates where to put the top-fade as the page is scrolled
            var bgNP2 = -(($win.scrollTop() - $this.offset().top)/ scroll_speed1);

            //this calculates where to put the bottom-fade as the page is scrolled (needs to be fixed once the above is fixed)
            var perDiff3 = percentDiff(bgP3, $this.outerHeight());
            var numberToSubstract3 = ($win.scrollTop() + percentOf($win.scrollTop(), perDiff3)) / scroll_speed1;
            var bgNP3 = bgP3 - numberToSubstract3 - bottomFade;

            //put the new values in the css
            var newValue = "center " + bgNP1 + "px," + "center " + bgNP2 + "px," + "center " + bgNP3 + "px";
            $this.css("background-position", newValue);

            });
        });
    });


    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) {
        $('body').on("mousewheel", function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var wd = event.wheelDelta;
            var csp = window.pageYOffset;
            window.scrollTo(0, csp - wd);
        });
    }

    //following this calculation: 
    //http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-difference-calculator.php
    function percentDiff(val1, val2) {
        var difference = ( (val1 - val2) / ((val1+val2) / 2) ) * 100;
        return difference;
    }

    function percentOf(percent, value) {        
        var n = percent/100;
        return n * value;
    }

    function percentChange(bigVal, smallVal) {
       var change = ( (smallVal-bigVal) / bigVal ) * 100;
       return 100 + change;
    }

});
```

Here is a recent [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m89brz60/6/). It might reflect minor changes here and there as I tried to get it straight, nothing too conspicuous.

I realize it's Christmas (though not where I live) but I hope someone will be able to make me see the light...